# CUDA not recognized on MacBookPro

Tags: cudalink

I am running 
Mma 11.1.0 on 
MacOS 10.12.4 on 
MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2014) with
NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M 2048 MB

I installed the Nvidia CUDA driver 8.0.71.

I evaluate

```
Needs["CUDALink`"]
```

And then

```
CUDAQ[]
```

and I get

```
False
```

What am I doing wrong?
I realize there are similar questions, but none recent.

Comment: see comments way down below [HERE](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/902394)

Comment: The newest version of Mma 11.1.1 advertises "Re-enabled GPU support for neural networks for Mac." But when I install on an Apple MacBook Pro with an NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M GPU, and I do: Needs["CUDALink`"] followed by CUDAQ[], I get False. Does Wolfram not support this GPU?